# .thumbnail file

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, insufficient-memory, thumbnails

.thumbnail file is occupying a lot of space in memory. I have very few pictures on the phone. Deleting doesn't work.

There were 2 previous questions regarding this which did not have a solution.

Have Android 5.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the DCIM Folder via any explorer app, generally the .thumbnail folder is  visible , if not then , tap on "Show hidden Files" from there you can delete the folder.

1. Deleted the thumbdata file (in DCIM/.thumbnails)
2. In Settings->Applications->All->Gallery: cleared data (only a few MB), (I would also have cleared the cache if there was anything there), then "Force stop"
3. In Settings->Applications->All->Media Storage: cleared data (only about 30MB), (I would also have cleared the cache if there was anything there), then "Force stop"
4. Restarted the phone

Original Source :  https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-thumbnails-data-from-my-DCIM-folder-in-Android

Comment: Did not work. The file seems to have got deleted but the space is still occupied.

Comment: have u tried the below link !